# IE 10 error- XMLDOM is not enabled

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a friend who uses a time attendance device from www.epordo.com. This solution uses Microsoft webserver with asp pages. He is using Internet Explorer (IE) version 10, and when he tries to display a list with employee attendance times he gets an error:

XMLDOM is not enabled

Is there some IE setting I'm missing? Is someone getting similar error and is this IE 10 error?

T.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has been deprecated in IE10. It should work if you put IE into compatibility mode. Either as a user by clicking the broken document icon in the url field, or as a developer by adding a meta element in the head to use the IE9 rendering mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Does this work?

Comment: No, but i used key F12 to open Developer Tools Interface, and the you can switch compatibility modes on/off.

This helped, so your answer put me to the right track.

10x dstorey :)